# Convert week number to date range with Saturday as beginning_of_week

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to use Saturday as the week start and calculate the beginning and the end of week from week numbers. I need week 53 to be properly accounted for as well.

```
Date.beginning_of_week = :saturday
```

works fine, but I have not found a way to generate week start and end dates only from a year and week number. `Date.commercial` is the only method I have been able to use thus far to convert a week number and year only to a date. I have been unable to get `Date.commercial` to recognize Saturdays as the week start.

Comment: 2013 started on a Tuesday. What's the week start and week end dates for the first week?

Comment: @Mike Sherrill 'Catcall': IIRC, the "normal" Day 1 of Week 1 2013 would be Monday 31 December 2012. Business year number can differ from the calendar year number at start and end of year. Typically the split is chosen so that the mis-match is less than 4 days (so sometimes the previous year extends into next year, sometimes it is vice-versa)

Answer (score 0):

> I need to use Saturday as the week start and calculate the beginning and the end of week from week numbers.

Given an instance of `Date` representing the first Saturday, and the week number, this is quite simple, unless I'm missing something.

```
def beginning_of_week(first_saturday, week_num) {
  return first_saturday + (7 * week_num.to_i).days
}
```

The `days` method comes from [activesupport](http://rubygems.org/gems/activesupport).